# Routes: multiple parameters for the application root

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to set up my MVC application with the root as follows:

- mysite.com/ -> Index action
- mysite.com/thingID -> to CurrentThing action
- mysite.com/thingID/year -> to CurrentThing action

Action: `public ActionResult CurrentThing(string thingID, int year)`

I also need the regular controller/action route to work both with and without an id. ThingID is a string. I have the following routes defined:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Regular",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "RootSpecificRecord",
            "{thingID}/{year}",
            new { controller = "Things", action = "CurrentThing", year = DateTime.Now.Year }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Root",
            "",
            new { controller = "Things", action = "Index" }
        );
```

This works fine until I go to mysite.com/id/year at which point the first route treats the id as a controller and the year as an action. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routing engine is unable to tell the difference between

`/{controller}/{action}/{id}`  and `/{ThingId}/{year}`

Since your id parameter is optional, and you don't have any constraints that ThingId is an id.

You could try putting the RootSpecificRecord route first, and altering the Id so that it will only accept an integer.  This will make it so it's more specific than your regular route.  Assuming ofcourse that thingID is an integer, you could alter your route like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "RootSpecificRecord",
            "{thingID}/{year}",
            new { controller = "Things", action = "CurrentThing", year = DateTime.Now.Year },
            new {thingID= @".*\d+.*" }
        );
```

See this [blog post](http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx) about route constraints, if you want to create a different constraint.

Comment: Whoops, I forgot to say that ThingID is a string, sorry.

Comment: Is ThingID something you can create a regex value for?  You need to create a more specific route than your regular route, and then put it above your default.

Comment: That makes sense. It seems that my ThingIDs all conatain numbers whereas my controller names do not. Perhaps this is the key. If this doesnt work, are there any other approaches you could suggest?

Comment: My regex isnt great, but I think I've updated the Regex to match anything that contains an integer.  Try moving that above your regular route, and see if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Default route must be last in your route tables

Comment: But then all regular controller/action/ requests get picked up as thingID/year and routed to my CurrentThing action.